# How do I put 2 "MaxButtons" buttons an a single line using shortcodes?

Tags: php

First -- here is my PHP

```
    <?php
    echo (  (do_shortcode('[maxbutton id="28"]')   )
         ) ;

    ?>


    <?php
    echo do_shortcode('[maxbutton id="29"]');
    ?>
```

Both of these work. BUT I GET a button on top of a button. I want a 2 buttons on the same-line;
next to each other. Ideas? I know PERL -- not PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 <?php echo ((do_shortcode(' [maxbutton ids="28, 29"] ')));?>
```